# Magento Filter search on search page

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, search, search-criteria

Is there any way around that I can filter search result using via search.

*Example* : Suppose I am on home page and there I searched "blue" in the search box.
Now I am on the search result page (`{{base_url}}/catalogsearch/result/?q=blue`), and my result contains all the related items like blue jeans, blue shirts, blue t-shirts, blue hats, etc.

Now I want if a user perform another search from the search result page, let say user enter **"hats"** in the search box, now instead of showing the result set containing hats. I want to show the result containing **(hats OR blue (OR is boolean operator here))**. Currently when I am performing search from the search result page, the result contains the result for the new term only.

Example : It is showing the result for hats only whereas I want the result for both blue and hats.

Please guide me how can I proceed on this.

Comment: You need to carry the existing `?q=blue` value in session and append it on next action. However filters server the same purpose

Comment: You need to combine search query.